# unity2d character y position equal bird y position

Tags: unity-game-engine, position

I want the bird to give my character coin if the character y position equal the bird y position I did this code but it's not work

```
    public Transform target;
public GameObject Coin;

void Update () {
    transform.Translate (Vector2.left * 10f * Time.deltaTime);
    if (transform.position.y == target.position.y) {
        Instantiate (Coin, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }

}
```

Comment: So, the bird is flying left the whole time and once the y-pos is the same, you spawn the coin. Can you give us a screenshot of your scene?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i want

Comment: @bastingup the website not allow me to put pic

Comment: I am not quit sure if the "==" operator will do the trick. So the player can also be above the bird? If so you might wanna try ">=" (if the player is above the bird), because floats are crazy precise, maybe the condition is just never happening cuz the player is alwayslike 0.0001f below or above? Then you also need a private bool, checking whether the coin has already been given. right now you are giving like 100 coins per second (depending on you frame rate).

Comment: all is work fine but when  the character y position equal the bird y position it'not give me any coin

Comment: Does it actually equal? Put a Debug.Log("Same y pos."); in the if-statement and check, whether it's actually happening

Comment: when i did >= i get alot of coin

Comment: can 1 bird only give 1 coin and then the bird is done?

Comment: @bastingup it didn't show the msg then that's mean they didn't give the same y position when they meet so i want to change my question to how to get near or equal y character position to y bird position

Comment: @bastingup yes no problem

Comment: well, check the answer below

Comment: @bastingup not work at all and it works with >= but it gives me the coin when the game start before reach to the character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have answered it yourself in the comments. The character is never EXACTLY the same y-pos like the bird, so you gotta check whether the character is above the bird. Try this:

```
public Transform target;
public GameObject Coin;
private bool _birdGaveCoin = false;

void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector2.left * 10f * Time.deltaTime);
    if (transform.position.y <= target.position.y && !_birdGaveCoin)
    {
        Instantiate(Coin, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        _birdGaveCoin = !_birdGaveCoin;
    }
}
```

So to wrap it up: floats are crazy precise. So can be that one frame your character is at 3.99999f and the bird is at 4.00000f and the next frame the player is at 4.00001f, so it's technically not the same.

Comment: hey bro looks like your code work only when i jump more the bird itself

Comment: thanks, bro because you i know now the answer the answer is below

Comment: @SHOWCASE in your question you explicitly asked for the `y position` so you should rather accept this answer.

Comment: All good man, no need to go into details, he figured it out himself

Answer (score 0):

**the answer is putting x not the y this code answer the question**

```
void Update () {
        transform.Translate (Vector2.left * 10f * Time.deltaTime);
        if (transform.position.x <= target.position.x&&coin==false) {
            Instantiate (EvilEgg, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            coin=true;
                    }

        }
```